# Build a vector as a subset of another one without copying

Tags: c++, vector, containers, move

Let `v` be a vector. I would like `w` to be a subset of `v` between the indices `from` and `to`. I could just do

```
std::vector<T> w(v.begin() + from, v.begin() + to);
```

However, I do not intend to use `v` in the future. As such, I don't need to copy the data between `from` and `to`. I would need to create a vector who points to `v.begin() + from` and is of length `to - from`. The rest of the memory used by `v` should be freed. Note that I am fine if it is `v` being redefined (I can just swap to `w` afterward if I want to anyway).

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Regarding your question about whether you should use `std::deque`, that entirely depends on how you're using this vector.  Remember that a deque's storage is not contiguous in memory.  Also, the amount of memory used by a deque is generally more than that used by a vector, weakening your point about needing to freeing parts of memory outside the range.  You don't have a lot control over that with a deque.

Comment: @paddy Yes, I realized there is not enough info for this extra question. I removed `SHould I use a deque` frmo my post. FYI, I mean to subset these vector a lot, sometimes where copying is necessary, sometimes it is not. I also need fast (if possible, constant time) look-up.

Comment: I doubt if it is possible in vector: Internal of vector is simply a big piece of continuous memory, and I doubt you have any way to free up only part of such block of memory.  Just think of it: if you have `int* foo = new int [1000];` Are there any way you can free up, let's say, from `foo[0]` to `foo[50]`? imho it is not possible

Comment: It is possible if you write your own memory allocator that can segment a block and return the parts around it.  Although it may not be possible to use that allocator with a vector.  Of course, if engineering for very specific requirements like this, that might be the way you need to go, along with your own container to wrap that functionality.  Note that this may lead to more excessive memory fragmentation than you might get with standard allocators and a bit of copying.

Comment: Is moving the data (`T`) ok for you (which is copy for type as `int`) ?

Comment: @Remi.b you can see some details for deque that you may already know in my deque answer. paddy's concern about whether you need contiguous allocation is on point though, but the performance should be almost exactly the same since the lookup is constant time with two indirections only, just 1 more than vector, and depending on the size of the buckets of the deque, the maximum amount of wasted memory you'd persist on the front and back buckets. I'd dare to say that in almost any PC situation I can think of right now I'd use deque.

Comment: And actually std::deque can be even faster than vector since you have the certainty that the elements will never be copied to another array when the container has to grow, it just allocates/frees a new bucket!

Comment: Just make sure like @paddy said that you do not need contiguous allocation

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `vector`, there is no way to avoid copying.  If you want to be sure unused memory is released, you could do it like this :

```
std::vector<T> w(v.begin() + from, v.begin() + to);
std::vector<T>().swap(v);
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that unused memory is released. The best option is `w.clear(); w.shrink_to_fit();` but that also does not guarantee (there is no way to guarantee)

Comment: @M.M, What you suggest does not come with a guarantee. What I suggest makes sure that `v` is a fresh empty `vector` and that the previous contents of `v` goes out of scope at the semicolon.

Comment: Neither way guarantees (there is no way to guarantee)

Comment: @M.M, I guess we disagree on this.

Comment: @SidS: No guaranty that the new empty vector has capacity of 0.

Comment: @Jarod, It seems reasonable to assume that a new empty `vector` has the lowest possible memory use for a `vector`.

Comment: @SidS: Same for `shrink_to_fit`/`clear`... but no guaranty :-/

Comment: @Jarod, Not the same.  It's not reasonable to make that assumption for `shrink_to_fit()` as [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) for it explicitly states that you can't make that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick with vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{ 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99 };
    constexpr size_t from = 3;
    constexpr size_t to = 7;

    if(to < v.size() - 1)
        v.erase(v.begin() + to, v.end());

    if(from > 0)
        v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin() + from - 1);

    v.shrink_to_fit();

    for(auto i : v)
        cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: When erasing elements at the start, you actually copy elements over to the first positions. It does not move the begin iterator.

Comment: @Remi.b Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @MichaelSurette try it with a class whose move-assignment operator outputs something

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a std::deque, and pop all the elements from begin() to begin() +front, and from end() - to to end(). That will free the unusded memory minus a tiny chunk from the front of the first bucket and the end of the last bucket. std::deque is very performant, since it stores its contents in buckets of arrays. It is not just as performant as vector, but it's in practice probably good enough since its just 1 extra level of indirection.
Roughly this is the difference:

- std::vector [i] -> return buffer[i]
- std::deque[i] -> buckets[i] -> return bucket[i];

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

It depends on how much you grow and shrink your vector, but deque shrinks and grows whithout copying any elements ever, its just bucket allocation/deallocation. So it can be much more performant than vector in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

[Should be available soon.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) In the meantime, your options are:

1. Use `std::string<T>` rather than `vector`, and, consequently, [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).
2. Craft your own view class. Say,

   ```
   template<class Iterator> class view {
       Iterator b, e;
   public:
       view(Iterator b, Iterator e): b(b), e(e) {}

       auto &operator[](std::size_t i) { return *(b[i]); }
       auto const &operator[](std::size_t i) const { return *(b[i]); }
       auto begin() const { return b; }
       auto end() const { return e; }
       auto size() const { return e - b; }
   };
   ```

Comment: Even with ranges it wouldn't free the memory. I guess he needs another container. Because for this purpose he could as well simply save the whole vector and the iterators. IMHO

Comment: Oh, I've missed that rest of the memory part. 0_o